# Facebook access_token response format for old API

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, authentication, oauth

I am working with old version of Facebook access_token endpoint. But i cant find description of expires value returned by the server..

The value is: `5183764`

What is it? Seconds token expires in? I have tried to convert the current Linux epoch time + returned into date and the token would expire in October.. Is it OK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is it? Seconds token expires in?

Yes, it’s the seconds until the token expires. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow#exchangecode

> I have tried to convert the current Linux epoch time + returned into date and the token would expire in October.. Is it OK?

About two month is the lifetime of an extended user access token, so yeah – that sounds o.k.